# What is the common way to strip out the parent directory from the path in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say the path is /foo/bar/baz.json and I want /bar/baz.json. What's the general way of doing that using nodejs path?

Comment: I can think of 3 off the top of my head, but I wouldn't call any of them preferred over the others

Answer (score 3):

There is a built in function for that in Node.js:

```
require('path').relative('/foo', '/foo/bar/baz.json');
// 'bar/baz.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var path = require('path');

var myPath = "/foo/bar/baz.json";

var pathItems = myPath.split(path.sep);

pathItems = pathItems.splice(2);
var result = path.sep + pathItems.join(path.sep);

console.log(result);

// "/bar/baz.json"
```

You might use `path.isAbsolute()` to decide what to do with the first `"/"`.